# how to sort data in csv file using python using particular column

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading data from csv file and trying to sort data by using particular column for example reading data to 100 students from csv file and have to sort data according to marks

```
import csv
import operator

with open('Student_Records.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(7), reverse=True)

for eachline in sortedlist:
    print(eachline)

csvFile.close()
```

csv file in excel sheet and that file doesn't have column names, following is the csv file data

```
1,Lois,Walker,F,lois.walker@hotmail.com,Donald Walker,Helen Walker,40,303-572-8492
2,Brenda,Robinson,F,brenda.robinson@gmail.com,Raymond Robinson,Judy Robinson,80,225-945-4954
3,Joe,Robinson,M,joe.robinson@gmail.com,Scott Robinson,Stephanie Robinson,70,219-904-2161
4,Diane,Evans,F,diane.evans@yahoo.com,Jason Evans,Michelle Evans,90,215-793-6791
5,Benjamin,Russell,M,benjamin.russell@charter.net,Gregory Russell,Elizabeth Russell,56,262-404-2252
6,Patrick,Bailey,M,patrick.bailey@aol.com,Ralph Bailey,Laura Bailey,36,319-812-6957
7,Nancy,Baker,F,nancy.baker@bp.com,Scott Baker,Judy Baker,78,229-336-5117
```

Comment: I think you have done it yourself: `key=operator.itemgetter(7)`, you need to change your key. Post a part of your csv for further help?

Comment: 1 Lois Walker F lois.walker@hotmail.com Donald Walker Helen Walker 40 303-572-8492
2 Brenda Robinson F brenda.robinson@gmail.com Raymond Robinson Judy Robinson 80 225-945-4954
3 Joe Robinson M joe.robinson@gmail.com Scott Robinson Stephanie Robinson 70 219-904-2161
4 Diane Evans F diane.evans@yahoo.com Jason Evans Michelle Evans 90 215-793-6791
5 Benjamin Russell M benjamin.russell@charter.net Gregory Russell Elizabeth Russell 56 262-404-2252
6 Patrick Bailey M patrick.bailey@aol.com Ralph Bailey Laura Bailey 36 319-812-6957

Comment: Edit your question with this.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and ad a formatted part of your csv to your question

Comment: @GeethaTabjul Is the input a csv or tsv? There are no commas.

Comment: it's an csv file i.e.. excel sheet stored as .csv extension

Comment: Where are the commas then? what is the delimiter being used?

Comment: Have you considered just using `pandas` to read the csv and the `DataFrame sort_values` method should do what you are looking for?

Comment: @GeethaTabjul When you open it in excel, you probably won't see the commas as excel interprets them to display the data in cells. Open it in a text editor. Copy that and then add it to your question.

Comment: i need code how to sort csv file data by using particular column like marks column

Comment: Just make a Pandas data frame and do "" **df.sort_values('Your column name')** ""

Comment: Okay, I was able to  sort your csv by marks based on some assumptions I made, check my answer @GeethaTabjul and check if it makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    l = sorted(rdr, key=lambda x: x[6], reverse=True)
```

`csv.reader()` is used to create a reader object which is sorted using `sorted()` with `reverse=True` for descending order sort to obtain a list.

This list can be used to write out an output csv using something like

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    wrtr = csv.writer(csvout)
    wrtr.writerows(l)
```

The output csv file would be something like

```
4,Diane   Evans,F,diane.evans@yahoo.com,Jason Evans,Michelle Evans,90,215-793-6791
2,Brenda  Robinson,F,brenda.robinson@gmail.com,Raymond Robinson,Judy Robinson,80,225-945-4954
3,Joe Robinson,M,joe.robinson@gmail.com,Scott Robinson,Stephanie Robinson,70,219-904-2161
5,Benjamin    Russell,M,benjamin.russell@charter.net,Gregory Russell,Elizabeth Russell,56,262-404-2252
1,Lois  Walker,F,lois.walker@hotmail.com,Donald Walker,Helen Walker,40,303-572-8492
```

---

Since you are reading the data from a file object, specify the `newline` parameter as `''` to be safe.

As the docs say:

> If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

> If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

Answer (score 1):

Below should work for you, I created a list of rows after reading the csv such that the marks are actually integers, instead of strings when they are read from the csv

Also I am assuming multiple whitespaces in csv, so I have used a whitespace delimiter so  itemgetter index is chosen as 9, which might be different based on how your csv looks like

```
import csv
import operator

li = []

#Open csv file
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True )

    #Create a list of all rows such that the marks column is an integer
    for item in reader:
        #Save marks value as an integer, leave other values as is
        l = [int(value) if idx == 9 else value for idx, value in enumerate(item)]
        li.append(l)

#Sort on that item
print(sorted(li, key=operator.itemgetter(9), reverse=True))
```

My csv looks like:

```
1   Lois    Walker  F   lois.walker@hotmail.com Donald Walker   Helen Walker    40  303-572-8492
2   Brenda  Robinson    F   brenda.robinson@gmail.com   Raymond Robinson    Judy Robinson   80  225-945-4954
3   Joe Robinson    M   joe.robinson@gmail.com  Scott Robinson  Stephanie Robinson  70  219-904-2161
4   Diane   Evans   F   diane.evans@yahoo.com   Jason Evans Michelle Evans  90  215-793-6791
5   Benjamin    Russell M   benjamin.russell@charter.net    Gregory Russell Elizabeth Russell   56  262-404-2252
```

The output will look like

```
[['4', 'Diane', 'Evans', 'F', 'diane.evans@yahoo.com', 'Jason', 'Evans', 'Michelle', 'Evans', 90, '215-793-6791'], 
['2', 'Brenda', 'Robinson', 'F', 'brenda.robinson@gmail.com', 'Raymond', 'Robinson', 'Judy', 'Robinson', 80, '225-945-4954'], 
['3', 'Joe', 'Robinson', 'M', 'joe.robinson@gmail.com', 'Scott', 'Robinson', 'Stephanie', 'Robinson', 70, '219-904-2161'], 
['5', 'Benjamin', 'Russell', 'M', 'benjamin.russell@charter.net', 'Gregory', 'Russell', 'Elizabeth', 'Russell', 56, '262-404-2252'], 
['1', 'Lois', 'Walker', 'F', 'lois.walker@hotmail.com', 'Donald', 'Walker', 'Helen', 'Walker', 40, '303-572-8492']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Pandas,

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_file", sep='xx', 
              names = ["x", "y", "z", "marks"])

df.sort_values('marks')

print(df)
```