# csv.reader / writer - why does iterating CSV object result in no output from writer?

Tags: python, csv, iterator

I found [this example of a simple CSV read / write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946734/how-to-sort-data-in-csv-file-using-python-using-particular-column/55947291).

This code reads and writes the CSV file, sorting on the 7th column.

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    l = sorted(rdr, key=lambda x: x[6], reverse=True)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    wrtr = csv.writer(csvout)
    wrtr.writerows(l)
```

The code above outputs a CSV file into output.csv

If I need to do some additional processing other than sorting, I might do it by iterating through the rows of the CSV object.  The simplest example exhibiting the problem is just iterating the rows and printing them:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for arow in rdr:
        print(arow)
    l = sorted(rdr, key=lambda x: x[6], reverse=True)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    wrtr = csv.writer(csvout)
    wrtr.writerows(l)
```

The code above prints the CSV rows to the screen as expected.
However, the output.csv file is then empty ( 0 bytes)

Why does iteration through the rows cause no output from csv.writer? Is there some type of persistent state in the CSV object that has to be reset?

Comment: `rdr` is an iterator. You can only loop through an iterator once. Convert it to a list if you want to process it multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for fast response! I didn't realize rdr was an iterator.  Adding `mylist = list(rdr)` and using mylist is the solution.

Comment: @tim11g: Please add this as a response and accept so that the question does not hang open.

Answer (score 0):

As  @Barmar correctly noted:

> rdr is an iterator. You can only loop through an iterator once.
> Convert it to a list if you want to process it multiple times.

Working code:

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    mylist = list(rdr)
    for arow in mylist:
        print(arow)
    l = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: x[6], reverse=True)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    wrtr = csv.writer(csvout)
    wrtr.writerows(l)
```